# How to stop the backspace for particular element in jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript and I am making a web application. Basically its a simple memo using html5.

My html code:

```
<ul contenteditable="true">
   <br/>abc<br/>
   def<br/>
   ghi<br/>
</ul>
```

and my javascript:

```
window.onkeydown = backspace;

function backspace() {  
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
    var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
        var li = lis[i];

        if (li.innerHTML == "<br>") {
            if (!li.id) {
                li.id = "ttt";
                if (key == 8) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }   
    }    
    return true;
}
```

I tried the basic backspace return false but the problem is if the `li` tag is empty the other `li` tags will not take the backspace event even if it has a character.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent content from being deleted in all cases or just specific parts of the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add event handler to document keypress
then check if backspace and the type of element you want 'LI'

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {

            var key = e.which;

            if (key == 8 && e.target.attributes[0].value != "text") {
                return false;
            }

        });
```

you can can replace text with the type of element you want

Comment: yes you are right there are 3 li tags i want to stop the backspace when the li tag is empty the problem is the backspace will stop for that element and all the other elements so
i made my function set an id for the particular element when i get the element var l=doc.getlementbyid(ttt) 
if(l.innerhtml=="<br>"){
key==8
return false;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 8) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('we arent allowing deletes');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dq8tr/3/